# in redshift postgresql can I skip columns with the copy function

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

- I have a .csv table (t1) with columns: c1, c2, c3 in amazon S3 storage
- I want to copy that into amazon redshift
- I create the table with columns: c1, c2, c3 where all columns are nullable
- I copy with command:

  copy t1a (c1,c3)
  from t1
- I expected it would copy c1 and c3 over from t1 and place the default null value in c2 so a row in t1a might look like (c1_rowX, null, c3_rowX).
- Instead I get a type error because it's coping c2 (string type) data from t1 into c3 (int type) of t1a.
- the copy command works fine when I don't specify the columns:

  copy t1a
  from t1
- I've included a link to the redshift copy command documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html

- main question is there an issue with my use of specifying columns.  thanks

Answer (score 14):

If you want to skip preprocessing part, you can define the column to be skipped as `CHAR(1)` and then use a `TRUNCATECOLUMNS` parameter to a `COPY` command:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1a (
  c1,
  c2 CHAR(1),
  c3
);
COPY t1a FROM t1 TRUNCATECOLUMNS
```

The `TRUNCATECOLUMNS` ignores all data that is longer than defined in a table schema during the import, so all data in that column will be truncated into 1 character.

That's just a hack, preprocessing input file is recommended, but sometimes a hack is all that's needed.

Answer (score 5):

Detailed column-mappings are not supported in `COPY` directly, unless Amazon/ParAccel have added something extra to their PostgreSQL fork that isn't in mainline.

What you typically do in this case is have a script massage/pad the data - read the CSV, transform it as desired, then send the line through the PostgreSQL connection to a `COPY ... FROM STDIN` command.

Alternately, you might `COPY` the whole original CSV into a table then transform that data with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to the real target table.

Comment: thanks, Craig.  Hoping to avoid copying whole file due to size and time issues.  Might transform before copy.

Comment: amazon provides copy script template: COPY table_name [ (column1 [,column2, ...]) ] -- where (column1 [, column2, ...]) "specifies an optional column list to load data fields into specific columns"

Comment: @Elm Sure, but that doesn't let you say `COPY tablename(col1, SKIP, col3)` does it ... and that's what it seems you want? Even if Pg supported that it'd still have to transfer all the data to discard the parts you didn't want, so it makes a lot more sense to just do this client-side with a pre-processing script.