# Skip columns while copying data into redshift from S3 using copy command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I have a CSV table in S3 with 100's of attributes/features, I don't want to create table in RedShift with all these attributes before importing data. Is there anyway to select only the columns I need while copying data from S3 into Redshift?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in redshift postgresql can I skip columns with the copy function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17055708/in-redshift-postgresql-can-i-skip-columns-with-the-copy-function)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve the above using just a copy command it is doable using a python script. Please go through this

[Read specific columns from a csv file with csv module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16503560/read-specific-columns-from-csv-file-with-python-csv)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of options listed in aws forum for this problem, take a look at https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=432590 if they may work for you.