# Copy Redshift without table structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, copy, amazon-redshift

I would like to load a stagging table from S3 to Redshift via a copy instruction and then select some fields and create a final table, but I don't know how to load a file from s3 without knowing all the structure.

Let me explain with an example:

I have my file in s3

```
col1   col2   col3
a       1     b
b       4     c
```

I want a final table with only the col2 so I do the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stg(col1 varchar, col2 integer, col3 varchar);
COPY stg FROM myfile
CREDENTIALS
'aws_access_key_id=***;aws_secret_access_key=***'
 NULL as '' IGNOREHEADER AS 1
;
create table FINAL as
select
              col2
from stg
```

and I would like something like that (so I don't need to know the structure, only that it will have the col2):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE stg as (
COPY stg FROM myfile
CREDENTIALS
'aws_access_key_id=***;aws_secret_access_key=***'
 NULL as '' IGNOREHEADER AS 1
);

create table FINAL as
select
              col2
from stg
```

Comment: [amazon web services - Skip columns while copying data into redshift from S3 using copy command - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37712048/skip-columns-while-copying-data-into-redshift-from-s3-using-copy-command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing the correct process.

It is not possible to "skip over" columns when loading data via the `COPY` command.

The alternative would be to pre-process the files and remove the undesired columns *before* loading the data into Redshift.